# Is it possible to narrow a beam of electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Pardon me for naive question: is it possible to limit the 'beam width' of electromagnetic wave so it can warm an object at further distance?
If yes, then how.

Look at my figures below. I want to use radiant heater to heat an object. In the top picture, the object surface is heated OK. In the middle figure, it's placed a bit further so it doesn't receive enough heat. I want to have a solution like in the bottom figure, when the beam width is narrowed so that the same amount of energy is carried further, and it can heat the object well.

[image]

Comment: something like this ? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-38-200-BTU-Bronze-Heat-Focusing-Propane-Gas-Patio-Heater-HD10/308736197#overlay

Comment: @annav the link shows access denied...

Comment: @annav not quite, what you showed me changes the direction but doesn't narrow down the width of the beam (like a laser pointer) so it can heat up object at further distance.

Comment: Actually it does narrow the beam. Like a lens, a curved reflector has a focal length. If you put it the right distance from the heat source, it would focus the part of the beam that hits it onto the target. Like a lens, it does this by changing the direction of the light. In this case, the original "beam" spreads out over $360^o$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reflector (at least roughly parabolic) to focus the heat. To be effective, the reflector must be substantially larger than your IR source. You cannot efficiently collimate radiation using optics of the same size as your source. Small collimators work by absorbing much of the radiation, which doesn't help with your objective here.

Comment: thanks, looks like what I need is this goal "to cause the directions of motion to become more aligned in a specific direction" in the wiki article of collimator, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimator.

Comment: To clarify further, I need the collimator to not only "filter out" the waves not in the wanted direction, but rather reflect, re-align them so they can get through the filter. I'm not sure electromagnetic waves behave like visible light when going through lens. Do they?

Comment: Sure. Visible light *is* electromagnetic waves.

Answer (score 0):

This is done all the time in the electromagnetic realm of *radio waves*, in which "lenses" and "mirrors" can be fashioned out of metal rods and lengths of wire. For example, on my roof I have what is called a 5-element yagi antenna, which at a 2-meter wavelength acts just like a focusing lens and a reflective mirror to "shoot" a beam of electromagnetic waves mostly in one direction, which I can change at will by rotating the antenna assembly so it points at my intended target.

Answer (score 0):

Radiant heater normally heating up object using IR waves. In fact there are special lenses that able to focus IR spectrum, but they are [prohibitively expensive](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/70409).

But depent on the source the waves length can be range between [wavelengths from around 1 millimeter to the nominal red edge of the visible spectrum, around 700 nanometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared). Therefore if you want to focus the IR waves using lenses, you need to have a fixed waves length too.

So bassicly as `John Doty` said, using reflectors like to foucus the heat is more suitable for this kind of application. But be aware that IR also can be [absorb or redirect](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=22093) by molecules in air.

There is a startup that break rock by beam of electromagnetic waves [here](https://www.quaise.energy/)
Basicly they guide high-power millimeter waves though a tube, then the waves heating up rock until the rock broken. So the energy can be traver up to 20 km deep down as they claim.